# htaccess not working to remove folder from url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This website I'm working on right now is running in www.website.com/2012/, **it wasn't me**, but the root index file has a frame wich loads www.website.com/2012/home/index.php, and the other pages are loaded in the same structure www.website.com/2012/the-company/.

I could just take the 2012 folder and put the files on the root folder, right, but for reasons of bad coding I'm kinda afraid of messing up with the links and references. So, I'm using this .htaccess file to rewrite the URL, so it will run with the root URL. But this htaccess is not working, it is in the root and all of that, and the code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$   /2012/$1
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2012/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /2012/$1 [L,QSA]
```